# How do I add a route to an existing IOT hub using ARM template?

Tags: azure-resource-manager, azure-iot-hub

For most other Azure resources there are separate deployment types for subcomponents that can be individually deployed. For IOT hub I don't see any way to deploy routes/endpoints individually without including the entire IOT hub type. Furthermore there appears to be an error causing internal 500 errors if this IOT hub type does not come with SKU specified, which means I need to include SKU name/capacity in the ARM template which should work independant of this.

What am I missing?

[image: ARM template]

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure if I understand your question right. But if you want to add a route to an existing IoT Hub - which you presumably did not deploy using an ARM template?! You must therefore first build an ARM template the mimics the entire current IoT Hub configuration. When you deploy this ARM template, you should see no changes whatsoever to your existing IoT Hub. Then you add your new route to the template and deploy it again.

As a starting point you can use the "Export Template" feature from the Azure Portal on your existing IoT Hub.

You can find an example template here https://github.com/Azure/azure-quickstart-templates/blob/master/101-iothub-auto-route-messages/azuredeploy.json

Comment: What I am trying to do is have several modules which each can add their own routes to the iot hub during their deployment without changing any other configuration in the iot hub. Like how you add a subscription to a service bus topic, except this can be added as a separate type with its own template.

Comment: Yeah you cannot do that. Other way would be to use the Azure Management SDKs (or AZ CLI or PowerShell) and build something yourself that can partially modify your IoT Hub that way.